# certain lines in a multi-line text box in asp.net to be bold for side-heading

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am using asp.net and vb.net as code behind. In a webform, I want to use multi line text boxes. In those text boxes, I need to enter certain lines of text in bold. How to make it?

Edit:

I dont want user to change the content in multi-line text box. Its kind of an agreement i want to put up there. Once he check the check box, the content in multi line text box should show. Inside those multilines, i need some headings, bold, italics etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a rich textbox, there are several examples doing a google search. But, [here](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1636&lngWId=10) is one I found great.

Another great and [free rich text box](http://www.freetextbox.com/).

Regards

Comment: well, it looks like jQuery is needed. Could you edit your question with whole details? Just like the ones you are telling me at the comments.